# Why does using DUAL in a SELECT Statement of an MV impact the ability to determine the STALENESS of an MV?

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

We had Materialized view, MVJUNK1, that was FORCE refreshed on demand. Recently, a change was made to the MV to UNION will a result set from the DUAL table:

```
SELECT ColumnOne From RealTable
UNION
SELECT 'Literal Value' As ColumnOne FROM DUAL
```

As a result of this change, after refreshing the MV, the value of the ALL_MVIEWS.staleness column was UNKNOWN:

```
SELECT DMV.staleness,DMV.LAST_REFRESH_END_TIME, DMV.*  FROM ALL_MVIEWS DMV WHERE DMV.MVIEW_NAME = 'MVJUNK1'
```

When I changed the MV to avoid SELECTING from the DUAL pseudo table and instead did something like this:

```
SELECT ColumnOne From RealTable
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'Literal value' As ColumnOne FROM RealTable
```

...and then we refreshed the MV, the STALENESS of the MV was shown as FRESH.

I'd like to understand why using DUAL would impact the ability to determine the STALENESS of an MV. Any theories?

Comment: DUAl is a dummy table (one column and one row) of SYS schema. So "SELECT 'Literal Value' As ColumnOne FROM DUAL" will return 1 row only! But "SELECT DISTINCT 'Literal value' As ColumnOne FROM RealTable" will return "as many rows" as "the rows in realTable with value 'Literal value'. So the difference here is "from dual" return a single row and the other from 0 to n rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from the offical documentation

> UNKNOWN public static final MaterializedView.Staleness UNKNOWN Oracle
> Database does not know whether the materialized view is in a
> read-consistent view of its masters from any point in time (this is
> the case for materialized views created on prebuilt tables)

see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13403/oracle/javatools/db/ora/MaterializedView.Staleness.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping to understand what about using a DUAL table makes it impossible for oracle to determine the STATENESS of an MV, which as I understand it, indicates whether of now the MV needs to be refreshed. What is it about SELECT a literal value from a the DUAL  pseudo table, which is always deterministic, interferes with the ability to determine if the MV needs refreshing. I can think of nothing.

Comment: Please upvote or accept if it helps. Thank you